# cv2.fillConvexPoly and cv2.polylines yield different edges?

Tags: opencv, python

After drawing adjacent filled polygons with cv2.fillConvexPoly, edges between the polygons are drawn using cv2.polylines

**Expected behavior**: The edges nicely fit in between two drawn polygons

**Actual behavior**: Some edges actually lie inside one polygon! (see picture below)

[image]

**Code to reproduce**

```
# params
h,w = 20,30
points_yx = [(5, 1), (7, 22), (16, 13)]
points_xy = [(x,y) for y,x in points_yx]

# create voronoi partitiion
rect = (0, 0, w,h)
subdiv = cv2.Subdiv2D(rect)
subdiv.insert(points_xy)
polygons, centers = subdiv.getVoronoiFacetList([])
polygons_int = [np.round(poly).astype(np.int) for poly in polygons]

# draw voronoi polygons on image
img = np.zeros((h, w))
for i, poly in enumerate(polygons_int):
    color = i + 1
    cv2.fillConvexPoly(img, poly, color=color, lineType=cv2.LINE_8)
    x,y = points_xy[i]
    img[y, x] = 0

# draw borders of polygons
cv2.polylines(img, polygons_int, isClosed=False, color=0, thickness=0,
              lineType=cv2.LINE_8)

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.imshow(img, interpolation=None)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, at least one solution is to use `cv2.drawContours` for drawing the filled polygons as well as the polygon edges:

```
# params
h,w = 20,30
points_yx = [(5, 1), (7, 22), (16, 13)]
points_xy = [(x,y) for y,x in points_yx]

# create voronoi partitiion
rect = (0, 0, w,h)
subdiv = cv2.Subdiv2D(rect)
subdiv.insert(points_xy)
polygons, centers = subdiv.getVoronoiFacetList([])
polygons_int = [np.round(poly).astype(np.int) for poly in polygons]

# draw voronoi on image
img = np.zeros((h, w))
for i, poly in enumerate(polygons_int):
    cv2.drawContours(img, [poly], contourIdx=-1, color=i+1, thickness=cv2.FILLED)
    x,y = points_xy[i]
    img[y, x] = 0

# draw borders of polygons
cv2.drawContours(img, polygons_int, contourIdx=-1, color=0, thickness=0)

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.imshow(img, interpolation=None)
plt.show()
```

[image]